# How do I get value out of formView->EditItemTemplate->Textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have this FormView which should only have 1 record for editing:

```
    <asp:FormView ID="fmv_accountDetail" runat="server" DataKeyNames="UserID"
        DataSourceID="sds_accountDetail" DefaultMode="Edit" 
        emptydatatext="No employees found." 
        onitemcommand="fmv_accountDetail_ItemCommand"  >
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_UserID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserID") %>'  Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_CustomerName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("customerName") %>'  Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" 
                CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
        </EditItemTemplate>

    </asp:FormView>
```

How do I get the lbl_CustomerName in C#?  I would like to populate other labels with this value on the page.

Here is what I have been trying, but it say null error exception:

```
(fmv_accountDetail.FindControl("lbl_CustomerName") as Label).Text;
```

Comment: I think what you have should work ok, provided the FormView has data and it has been data-bound. FindControl(..) will probably return null if there is no data. However I can't remember off the top of my head when the data source will get data-bound. Try calling DataBind() on the FormView before using FindControl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem, and it was really easy too:

```
(fmv_accountDetail.Row.FindControl("lbl_CustomerName") as Label).Text;
```